# Python socket server not working when deployed

Tags: heroku, websocket, deployment, socket.io, python-socketio

I'm trying to build a chatbot, but I'm having some issues deploying my server

The program works locally, but when I try to deploy the server in Heroku, I keep receiving, "net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT". I tried everything but I can't find the solution for that.

Client:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>

   <script>
      var socket = io("http://bot.herokuapp.com:8080");
      
      function appendHtml(el, str) {
          el[0].innerHTML += str;
      }
      
      document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0].addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
          if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            sendMsg();
          }
      });
      
      function sendMsg() {
        var html = '<div class="message">' + document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0].value + '</div>';
        appendHtml(document.getElementsByClassName('messages'), html); 
        socket.emit("message", document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0].value);
        document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0].value = "";
      }
      
      socket.on("message", function(data) {
       var html = '<div class="message">' + data.response + '</div>';
       setTimeout(function(){ 
        appendHtml(document.getElementsByClassName('messages'), html); 
       }, 1000);
      });
   </script>
```

Server:

```
from aiohttp import web
import socketio
from chatbot.robot import getResponse

# creates a new Async Socket IO Server
sio = socketio.AsyncServer(cors_allowed_origins='*')
# Creates a new Aiohttp Web Application
app = web.Application()
# Binds our Socket.IO server to our Web App
# instance
sio.attach(app)

async def index(request):
    with open('index.html') as f:
        return web.Response(text=f.read(), content_type='text/html')

@sio.on('message')
async def print_message(sid, message):
    await sio.emit('message', {'response': getResponse(message)}, room=sid)

app.router.add_get('/', index)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app)
```

Heroku commands:

```
git push heroku master
heroku run python server.py
```

Heroku logs when I try to connect:

```
at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bot.herokuapp.com request_id=... fwd="..." dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

My procfile

```
web: python server.py
```

After I run the server.py, a message appears saying that the server is running at 0.0.0.0:8080

But I can't connect to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run inside Heroku you have to put your web server on the port number indicated in the `PORT` environment variable. Your code always puts it in 8080.

Try this:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8080))
    web.run_app(app, port=port)
```